# PHP XML Traversing gone awry

Tags: php, xml

I'm traversing an `xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wrapper>
  <site base="http://www.example1.co.uk/" name="example 1">
    <page>page1/</page>
  </site>
  <site base="http://www.example2.co.uk/" name="example 2">
    <page>page2/</page>
  </site>
</wrapper>
```

And my `php` is this:

```
xml = simplexml_load_file("siteList.xml");
foreach ($xml->site as $site => $child) {
  foreach ($xml->$site->page as $a => $page) { 
    $endUrl = ($child["base"] . "" . $page);
    print_r($endUrl . "<br />");
  }
}
```

This **technically** works, but returns the following:

```
http://www.example1.co.uk/page1/
http://www.example2.co.uk/page1/
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.example1.co.uk/page1/
http://www.example2.co.uk/page2/
```

It's using the `page` from the previous loop somehow, I cannot work it out :'(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be iterating over `$child` for the inner loop, but you are not. To fix it, change this

```
foreach ($xml->$site->page as $a => $page) {
```

to this

```
foreach ($child as $page) { // you don't even need the $a
```

You could also simplify the outer loop to `foreach ($xml->site as $child)` as you don't care about the key; and if you do this, renaming `$child` to `$site` would be a logical next step to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* using the `page` from the previous loop. Perhaps this change will help:

```
xml = simplexml_load_file("siteList.xml");
foreach ($xml->site as $site => $child) {
  foreach ($site->page as $a => $page) { 
    $endUrl = ($child["base"] . "" . $page);
    print_r($endUrl . "<br />");
  }
}
```